# Weblogic Config Files - weblogic-application.xml, weblogic.xml, application.xml, web.xml

Tags: java, xml, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I am aware of 4 configuration files we use for **WebLogic** :

1. web.xml
2. weblogic.xml
3. weblogic-application.xml
4. application.xml

What is the purpose of using each of these files ?

Comment: Too many questions. Please edit this to one question (if possible). Obviously, web.xml and application.xml are **not** weblogic specific.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The web.xml is the standard JEE descriptor for a WAR file. The application.xml is for the EAR file. The weblogic.xml and weblogic-appliation are WebLogic specific files for the WAR and EAR respectively. See sections A and B here:

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/toc.htm